# Why won't auto assign values of type long long?

Tags: c++, long-long

Using auto, I have created a variable number and used cin.get to get the value. I used this code to do so:

```
auto number = cin.get();
cout << typeid(number).name() << endl;
```

It seems that even if I enter a number that is over 2147483647, the value still gets assigned type int. Why is this? Shouldn't auto be assigning a value of type long if the number exceeds the max 32 bit int value?

Comment: `auto` is resolved at compile time, meaning that it has already decided the type should be `int` before you ever even run the program.

Comment: Firstly: `cin.get()` doesn't do what you think it does. Secondly: what Frxstrem said.

Comment: You seem to have an incorrect idea of what auto does. auto deduces the type of the variable at compile time. What you input at runtime has no effect on the variable,s type. If you input "hello world" it won't magically become a string.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I see now, I can literally enter anything and get a return value of int if I use cin,I must initialize the value before compiling :p

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`auto` is resolved at compile-time, and decided based on the return type of `cin.get()` (which happens to be `int` *by definition*).

In addition, the expression `typeid(number).name()` is also evaluated at compile-time, meaning that the compiler resolves this to a constant value (e.g., `"i"` for my system) and stores that in the executable.

Comment: + 1, but to clarify slightly: `auto` is *inherently* compile-time, whereas `typeid` is compile-time here only because the compiler can predict what the result will be in this case (because the argument is not a polymorphic reference). (And it's also worth pointing out that `cin.get()` actually means something quite different from what the OP thinks. It just returns a single character, e.g. `'2'`, not an entire integer. The OP is probably getting confused by line-buffering.)

Comment: Strictly speaking, even if the compiler _can_ predict what the result will be, for a polymorphic reference the `typeid` expression still needs to be evaluated at runtime for potential side effects.

Answer (score 2):

`auto` is resolved on compile-time. The compiler deduced that `number` is of type `int` because `std::istream::get` returns an `int`.

If this is a problem, use `long long` explicitly here.

Answer (score 1):

So `auto` doesn't change anything. And neither `istream::get()` nor `istream::getline()` actually parses the input to see if it is a number.

But let's look at some options:

### `cin.get()`

This returns an int that represents one character of the input stream. But it represents a character, not a number.

### `cin.getline()`

This is an error.
There's no overload of `istream::getline()` that expects no arguments.

### `char s[100]; cin.getline(s, 100);`

This will store a line of the input (or 100 characters if it is too long) and store it in the string `s`.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what's already been said about `auto`…

It is impossible to "enter a number that is over 2147483647" here. `cin.get()` is *unformatted input*. You are reading *bytes*, and bytes (assuming `CHAR_BIT==8`) only go up to `255`. That is why `cin.get()` returns an `int`: it will *never* any higher value. Ever.